# Concatenate the last letter onto a strip of code (Linq?)

Tags: vb.net, linq

For a boardgame i'm designing in visual basic I have 6 picture files named 1,2,3,4,5, and 6.

I'm generating a random Integer between 1 and 6. Basically if the Integer is a 2 I want a 2 to be concatenated onto `My.Resources._` to become `My.Resources._2` , etc

I tried something along the lines of `My.Resources._ & DiceRoll` but it doesn't work. I assume I have to use a Linq perhaps?

```
 Function RollDice()
        Dim DicePic() As PictureBox = {PictureBox3, PictureBox2}
        Dim DiceRoll = Int(Rnd() * 6 + 1)
        DicePic(DiceNumber).Image = My.Resources._

    End Function
```

Comment: You can't do it the way your wanting. Use a Function to return the image based on your dice roll.

Answer (score 0):

You have to either pre load the resources to an array or use a Select Case.

```
Dim ResourcesArray As New ArrayList()
Function PreLoad()
    ResourcesArray.Add(My.Resources._1)
    ResourcesArray.Add(My.Resources._2)
    ResourcesArray.Add(My.Resources._3)
    ResourcesArray.Add(My.Resources._4)
    ResourcesArray.Add(My.Resources._5)
    ResourcesArray.Add(My.Resources._6)
End Function

...
DicePic(DiceNumber).Image = ResourcesArray(DiceRoll)
...
```

Or

```
Function ResourceFind(Index As Integer)
    Select Index
       Case 1: Return(My.Resources._1)
       Case 2: Return(My.Resources._2)
       Case 3: Return(My.Resources._3)
       Case 4: Return(My.Resources._4)
       Case 5: Return(My.Resources._5)
       Case 6: Return(My.Resources._6)
    End Select
End Function

...
DicePic(DiceNumber).Image = ResourceFind(DiceRoll)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Function DiceImage(diceSide As Integer) As Image
 Dim resultImg As Image = Nothing
 Select Case index
   Case 1
     resultImg = My.Resources._1
   'etc...
 End Select
 Return resultImg
End Function
```

Usage:

```
Private Sub RollDice()
 Dim DicePic() As PictureBox = {PictureBox3, PictureBox2}
 Dim DiceRoll = Int(Rnd() * 6 + 1)
 DicePic(DiceNumber).Image = DiceImage(DiceRoll)
End Sub
```